# is it possible to place a column name in parameters in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to below

```
Date   |field1  | qty1 | qty2 | qty3
1 Aug  | xyz    | 0    | 0    | 3
1 Aug  | xyz    | 3    | 0    | 0
1 Aug  | abc    | 0    | 5    | 0
2 Aug  | abc    | 0    | 15   | 0
2 Aug  | xyz    | 0    | 12   | 0
2 Aug  | xyz    | 5    | 0    | 0
```

I have written three stored procedures to display each quantity separately as below.

This is my first procedure

```
create procedure firstprocedure 
@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
As
select date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz', qty1) as XYZ,
sum (case when field1 = 'abc', qty1) as ABC 
from table1
where date between @startdate and @enddate
group by date
```

This is my second procedure

```
Create procedure secondprocedure
@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
As
select date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz', qty2) as XYZ,
sum (case when field1 = 'abc', qty2) as ABC 
from table1
where date between @startdate and @enddate
group by date
```

This is my third procedure

```
Create procedure thirdprocedure 
@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
As
select date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz', qty3) as XYZ,
sum (case when field1 = 'abc', qty3) as ABC 
from table1
where date between @startdate and @enddate
group by date
```

I wonder is there any chance I just place the columns(whether qty1, qty2, or qty3) in parameters and while executing just mention if I want qty1 or qty2 or qty3. It should produce output accordingly.

Comment: It would be better, if possible, to normalize the table before continuing. There ought to be a column (`qtytype`) that stores the type of quantity being dealt with (one of `1`, `2` or `3`) and then a *single* `qty` column containing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

create a procedure like this:

```
create procedure my_procedure(@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime,@qty_type varchar(50))
as
begin 
    with cte as( 
    select 'qty1' [col_name],date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz' then qty1 end) as XYZ,
    sum (case when field1 = 'abc' then qty1 end) as ABC 
    from table1
    where date between @startdate and @enddate
    group by date
    union all 
    select 'qty2' [col_name],date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz' then qty2 end) as XYZ,
    sum (case when field1 = 'abc' then qty2 end) as ABC 
    from table1
    where date between @startdate and @enddate
    group by date
    union all
    select 'qty3' [col_name],date, sum (case when field1 = 'xyz' then qty3 end) as XYZ,
    sum (case when field1 = 'abc' then qty3 end) as ABC 
    from table1
    where date between @startdate and @enddate
    group by date
    )select * from cte where [col_name]=@qty_type
end
```

then execute it with:

```
exec '2012-04-01','2012-05-01','qty1'
```

or

```
exec '2012-04-01','2012-05-01','qty2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName
    @ColumnName NVARCHAR(100),
    @startdate datetime, 
    @enddate datetime
AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'
    select date, sum (case when field1 = ''''xyz'''', ' + @ColumnName + ') as XYZ,
    sum (case when field1 = ''''abc'''', ' + @ColumnName + ') as ABC 
    from table1
    where date between ' + CONVERT(DateTime, @startdate, 101) + 
        ' and ' + CONVERT(DateTime, @enddate, 101) +
    'group by date'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

You can call the Stored Procedure in this way (from SQL):

```
EXEC procedureName 'qty1', '01/01/2012', '01/01/2011'
```

**NOTE**

Where I have used `CONVERT(DateTime, @startdate, 101)`, you will have to change the style value (currently `101`) to meet your requirements of the date format you are using. Please refer to this page for details: [MSDN CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...can you please let me know how I can execute the procedure with parameters? And also I modified the original question for data parameters...

Comment: @user1449596 I have updated my answer in line with your changes.

Comment: Thanks Alex
Shall I need to write exec (@sql) also? If I don't write it displays "command(s) successfully completed" but no output is shown. If I write exec(@sql) it shows error `incorrect syntax near 'xyz'

Comment: The `EXEC(@SQL)` is the command to actually runs the dynamic SQL that you have put into the `@SQL' parameter. I have changed my code slightly so that the incorrect syntax error is resolved... its down to the `'` characters.